# Add change event on hidden checkbox

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to catch change event, or at least click event on the checkbox. I've read that when `"visibility : hidden"` or `"display:none"`, the event is not fired. Then I add `eventListener` to a label but it seems not working too. Can't understand how to make work.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var gameCount = document.getElementsByClassName("innerCount")[0];
  var checkLabel = document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox] + label");
  checkLabel.addEventListener("onclick", function() {
    if (checkLabel.checked) {
      gameCount.innerHTML = "--";
      console.log("turnOn");
    } else {
      gameCount.innerHTML = "";
      console.log("turnOff");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.checkbox > input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #424242;
}
.checkbox > label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #a50005;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox > input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  right: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div id="switcher">
  <span class="labels">ON</span>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input id="checkMe" type="checkbox">
    <label for="checkMe"></label>
  </div>
  <span class="labels">OFF</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `change` event listener for checkbox fields.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var gameCount = document.getElementsByClassName("innerCount")[0];
  var checkLabel = document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
  checkLabel.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (checkLabel.checked) {
      gameCount.innerHTML = "--";
      console.log("turnOn");
    } else {
      gameCount.innerHTML = "";
      console.log("turnOff");
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**It's because the `addEventListener` `onClick` doesn't exist**. Please try with `click` :

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var gameCount = document.getElementsByClassName("innerCount")[0];
  var checkLabel = document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox] + label");
  checkLabel.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (checkLabel.checked) {
      console.log("turnOn");
    } else {
      console.log("turnOff");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.checkbox > input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #424242;
}
.checkbox > label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #a50005;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox > input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  right: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div id="switcher">
  <span class="labels">ON</span>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input id="checkMe" type="checkbox">
    <label for="checkMe"></label>
  </div>
  <span class="labels">OFF</span>
</div>
```